# Linked - list moving the last object in the list step back

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, linked-list, conditional-statements

i got for homework a question about a linked list.
i have a 2 classes of the linked list:

```
public class listOne
{
    private int _num;
    private listOne _next,_prev;

    public listOne (int n)
    {
        _num=n;
        _next=null;
        _prev=null;
    }

    public listOne (int num,listOne n,listOne p)
    {
        _num=num;
        _next=n;
        _prev=p;
    }
}
    public class listTwo 
    {
     private listOne _head,_tail;
     public listTwo ()
     {
         _head=null;
         _tail=null;
    }
    public listTwo (listOne h,listOne t)
    {
        _head=h;
        _tail=t;
    }
```

}

now, i need to write a boolean method that returns true if there is a sub-class who's average is equals to the given average by the user. and false if not, the method must be with the efficiency of o(n) and if its possible might be better with o(1)
the method will be written in the listTwo class.

I thought to  first, to calculate the average of all the list and count the number of numbers in the list , and check if the average equals to the given average.
if the average of the list is bigger than the given average, i will subtract
from the sum the last number from the list and move the last object of the list one step back and subtract 1 from the counting .
if the average of the list is smaller than the given average, i will subtract 
from the sum the first object and move the first object one step forward,and subtract 1 from the count variable .

i think this method should work but when i try to write it i'm kinda stuck.
I am trying to write a method that moving the last object one step back
can you tell me if this method is written correctly please? :

```
private listOne newEnd(listOne list)
{
listOne p=_head,prev=null;
while(p!=null&&p.getNext()!=null)
{
prev=p;
p=p.getNext();
}
if(p!=null&&p.getNext()==null)
{
prev.setNext(p);
}
return p;
}
```

this method should take the last object of the list one step back. 
is this correct?
thank you 
}

Comment: Have you tried to draw it out on paper?  What linkages do you expect between nodes before the call versus afterwards?

Comment: I guess you mean sub-*list* instead of sub-class?

Comment: Also, you seem have the following cases in your proposed solution: too big -> remove last element ; too small -> remove first element. 
This, however, only works if your list is sorted. I don't think it is, from what you wrote.

Comment: @Finomnis you are right, i forgot to say that the list is sorted

Comment: @Finomnis and yes i meant sub-list

Comment: @Jordan_boy that's quite an important detail to leave out ;) I that case, yes, your idea is correct, I think. But in your implementation, I think you got some wrong ideas. You don't actually 'move' anything while iterating. The list doesn't change. You just have 'look' at smaller and smaller parts of the list.

The important part to understand here is the difference between 'reference' and 'object'. The parts of your list are objects, the links between are references, they 'point' to the previous/next object. When you iterate, you also work with references.

Comment: To get the last element of the list as a reference, you just do in your listTwo class:
``listOne ref = _tail``. To move that reference by one, you do `ref = ref._prev`. Also, in my opinion, this is the perfect case to make _pref and _next public, or adding listTwo as a friend class.

Comment: Also, a couple of remarks for your coding style: classes always start with an uppercase. member variables do not need to start with an underscore. And your code formatting got horribly messed up while posting it here, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: @Finomnis 1 have two problems:
1. ref._prev is just a shortcut to  a method, but i don't have a method like it , how do i build it?

and other thing, for example when i say 
public listOne move(listOne list)
{
listOne ref=_head ;
ref.setNext(ref.getNext());
//what object should i return to get the change , the given list object or the ref object?
return?

thank you

Comment: @Jordan_boy I hope I won't offend you, but I feel like you didn't quite grasp a couple of basic principles in python or class-based programming in general. We could just give you a finished solution, but I think what you should really do is ask someone who does have the understanding for help, this would most likely benefit you more. Fixing the problems that you are having with this assignment will take more than 4-5 sentences on stackoverflow.

Comment: Why not just go through the list and calculate the average of the list *so far*. If you are on the `ith` element of the list, the average so far including the current element is `(avg * i + data) / (i + 1)`.

Comment: u didn't helped me guys :)